# error al pasar parametro tipo JSON

Tags: json, swift, api, swift3, swift4

cuando paso el parámetro que espera un JSON, me saca el error de que "cannot convert value type String to expected argument type JSON? ( aka 'Optional Dictionary(String, Any')

este es el dato

```
  var params: JSON = ["token": token, "system": "system", "dev": dev]

  if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, option: .prettyPrinted) {
  if let jsonString = String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: .ascii) {
```

y en esta función para mandar el dato son es donde me salta el error en jsonString, en la función espera un objeto de tipo JSON viene asi dentro de la función

```
  APICLient..... params: JSON? = nil...
```

y lo coloco de tal manera para que lo obtenga como JSON

```
  APICLlient.request(nil, method: .pos, path: .postupdate, params: jsonString) { (response, succees) in 

 // mas codigo ->
}
}
}
```

lo convierto por que no ejecuta o manda nil en la función ya que espera un JSON pero me salta ese error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas transformar tu `var params: JSON...` en data, ni luego a un jsonString...
Ya lo tienes como tipo JSON, que es el tipo que espera por lo que dice tu error, luego eso es lo que necesitas pasarle a tu función.

```
var params: JSON = ["token": token, "system": "system", "dev": dev]
APICLlient.request(nil, method: .pos, path: .postupdate, params: params) { (response, succees) in 

     // mas codigo ->
}
```

Comment: si, exactamente eso hice, pero como el segundo parámetro que es "system" me marcaba el error, pensé que tendría que convertir todo en JSON, pero salió mal ya que no lo toma como diccionario, lo toma como un solo String... pero lo solucioné simplemente creando en la función un parámetro tipo Any.. y cuando llamo a la funcion solo coloco "system"  y quedo bien... gracias!